# Why does "ебало" mean a face and "ебаться" mean to fuck?

Tags: значения, словоупотребление, мат

I had been talking with my Russian friend which used such words like "ебало", "ебаться" and "ебнутый". As I understood, this words have completely difference meaning. It is very curious.

Comment: the meaning of "Закрой своё ебало" is "close you mouth, shut up"

Comment: You have typically Russian friends. It's better for you and for Word culture to forget those words and read Dostoevsky's novels.

Comment: as different as 'fuck off', 'fuck up' and 'the fuck was that?'

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Original meaning of ***еба́ть*** is to fuck. This root comes from Proto-Indo-European language where it had the same meaning (***o̯i̯ebhoa̯*** “I fuck”).

The root later acquired some developments into the meaning “to beat”, (***въеба́ть***, ***вы́ебать***, means to beat somebody), possibly either because it is common to beat somebody into the reproductive organs or because fuck is associated with rape.

Further, еба́ло means a place where you can въеба́ть, i.e. beat. Since it is common to beat into the face, the word become to mean “a face that looks suitable to be beaten”.

Similarly, ***ёбнутый***, ***ебану́тый*** means somebody hit so hard that his consciousness is damaged. That is mad.

Other words with the same root include

- ***наеба́ть*** — to trick, cheat somebody;
- ***отъеба́ться*** — to leave alone, leave in peace somebody;
- ***заеба́ть*** — to annoy somebody out;
- ***еба́шить*** — to blindly beat, blindly shoot at a place or object (in military sence), also do something without a break, also go, move blindly;
- ***съеба́ть***, ***съеба́ться*** — to flee;
- ***проеба́ть*** — to lose something, for example, money, thing, opportunity;
- ***подъеба́ть*** — to joke on somebody unpleasantly, provoke;
- ***подъёбка*** — unfriendly joke, provocation;
- ***доёбываться*** — to importune, to pester;
- ***выёбываться*** — to epater, to show off, to strive to attract public attention with weird actions, to behave in an affected manner;
- ***довыёбываться*** — to finish badly due to own strive to show off;
- ***заеби́сь*** — well;
- ***заебо́н*** — quirk, idiosyncrasy, kink; also a good thing;
- ***недоёб*** — weird, aggressive, often misandric behavior of a woman due to the lack of sexual life.

Comment: "Закрой своё ебало" sounds strange if to think that "ебало" means "face". Don't you think?

Comment: Yellow Sky indeed, it mosyly meant the place where you can beat, I think it is the mouth area most often.

Comment: @YellowSky Why do you find it strange? There is a direct analogue in English in the form of "Shut your face", which is almost as vulgar and has been around for ages. I'm not sure about other European languages, but certainly wouldn't be surprised if there are other analogues.

Comment: Place to fuck is "еблище"

Comment: Also note the word *ебаный*, that means adjective *fucking*.

Comment: @Denis Kreshikhin еблище is augmentative of ебало

Comment: Could you provide a proof for your etymology of the verb and/or the words which are derivates of the root in other Indo-European languages? I always supposed it to be taken from mongols' language.

Comment: @Viridianus Greek οίφέω "I fuck", Old Indic यभति (yabhati) "fucks".

Comment: I don't agree. Etymology of "ебало" does not come from beating. It come from consonance with "хлебало"

Comment: еблище iterally means a huge ебло. And i would consider ебло and ебало two forms of the same word.

Comment: @Anixx then it would be natural if this root in this meaning stayed in modern European languages as water, mother, home, etc

Comment: Perhaps "закрой ебало" was derived from "запахни" , and the latter can mean both "shut it up" or "cover it"

Comment: @Arioch: If practically all other Indo-European languages used another word with a common source, this would be strange. But apparently this word got replaced more than once in language evolution! There are different words in modern English (=German,...) and French (=Spanish,...). This seems to be natural to me as the usage of these words is somewhat taboo, which encourages the creation of synonyms. Still, I would like to see one or two sources in the answer.

Answer (score 25):

There is a Russian word [**хлеба́ло**](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%85%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE) wich is a vulgar way to say “mouth”. It is derived from the verb [**хлеба́ть**](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%85%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C), “to eat liquid food with a spoon; to drink”, this verb is colloquial and stylistically neutral. **Xлеба́ло** is formed by the non-productive suffix **-л-** which is used to form the names of instruments:

> сиде́ть (to sit) — седло́ (saddle)
>    дыша́ть (to breathe) — ды́хало, дыха́ло (blowhole)
>    скрести́ (to scrape) — скребло́ (scraping knife)
>    ме́рить (to measure) — мери́ло (measure, criterion)

Since **хлеба́ть** rhimes with **еба́ть**, “to fuck”, so, by analogy, the word **хлеба́ло** got contaminated with **еба́ть**, and there appeared the word **еба́ло**, which is a still more vulgar way to say “mouth”. Later the meaning of the word got wider and it came to mean “face”, too, and now it means both.

Funny to say, but, although meaning “mouth”, from the etymological point of view the word **еба́ло** should have meant “penis, a thing to fuck with”. (-:

Comment: The -o in -ло is ending, not suffix.

Comment: What do u mean with the last sentence? I do not understand it enough.

Comment: @Anixx - Thank you for your corrections, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Some of the words you list (i.e. седло, may be скребло) come from PIE where the -l-om finalization, the -l- suffix plus -om ending of neuter(inanimate) gender was used for tools. Thus PIE ***sedlom*** gave Russian sedlo, English saddle, Gaul sedlon etc.

Comment: I think, it's because еба́ло is a place for fuck to.

Comment: 26 лет живу в России и вот наконец узнал :)

Comment: Вспомним Высоцкого:
Церковники хлебальники разинули
Замешкался немного Ватикан

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to point out that it is generally quite meaningless to ask "why" when to it comes to live languages, as they (languages) are the results of some "unorganized" collective authorship. 
Also, my apologies to the purists of Stack Exchange communities for stating this as an answer. I do realize that the most appropriate place for this will be a comment but it is not an option for me presently for the lack of reputation points.

Answer (score 1):

More often than not, "eбало" means "mouth". An eloquent example of this usage is the wording

"завали ебало",

which is the most rude and aggressive Russian equivalent to "shut the fuck up"
(and which version I would recommend you never to use, except to provoke a fight).

This wording bears an allusion to filling up a hole in the ground (on this occasion, a metaphor for one's mouth).

On rare occasions, however, "ебало" can denote the face as a whole. Here is an excerpt from Igor Rasteryaev's song about provincial girls:

Тупое ебало, хуйню несу я.
  Мой козырь единстванный --  жопа моя.

Answer (score 0):

I think that "Ебало" in Russian is equal to "mouth" because of oral sex )))
So "ебало" is something that is used as a target for "fuck".